# Изображение из поста вместо обложки WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Всем привет! Пытаюсь разобраться, почему не работает подставление изображения из поста на место обложки. Вот код из functions.php:

```html
//Вывод первой картинки в качестве изображения
function first_post_image() {
  global $post, $posts;
  $first_img = '';
  ob_start();
  ob_end_clean();
  $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
  $first_img = $matches [1] [0];
  if(empty($first_img)){
    // Указываем изображение поумолчанию
    $first_img = "/wp-content/themes/onballoon/img/noimg.png";
  }
  return $first_img;
}
```

Вот код, которым пытаюсь вызвать:

```html
<div class="posts row">
  <?php 
  $args = array('post_type' => 'post', 'category' => '-21' , 'orderby' => 'date', 'order'   => 'DESC', 'posts_per_page' => 4); 
  $posts = get_posts($args);
  foreach($posts as $post) { ?>

  <div class="posts-item col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="posts-item-container">
      <a href="<?php the_permalink( $post->ID ) ?>">
        <div class="posts-item-img">
          <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); } else { ?>
          <img src="<?php echo first_post_image() ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>">
          <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <div class="posts-item-content">
          <h3><?php echo get_the_title( $post->ID ) ?></h3>
          <p><?php echo get_the_excerpt( $post->ID ) ?></p>
          <p class="posts-item-date"><?php echo get_the_date() ?></p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <?php } ?>
</div>
```

В итоге выводит для всех одно последнее изображение из папки uploads. Как пофиксить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В цикле Вы упустили установку глобальной переменной setup_postdata($post).

Попробуйте так

```
<div class="posts row">
  <?php 
  
  $args = array('post_type' => 'post', 'category' => '-21' , 'orderby' => 'date', 'order'   => 'DESC', 'posts_per_page' => 4);
  
  $posts = get_posts($args);
  
  global $post;
  
  foreach($posts as $current_post) { ?>
  
  <?php $post = $current_post; ?>
  
  <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>

  <div class="posts-item col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="posts-item-container">
      <a href="<?php the_permalink( $post->ID ) ?>">
        <div class="posts-item-img">
          <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); } else { ?>
          <img src="<?php echo first_post_image() ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>">
          <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <div class="posts-item-content">
          <h3><?php echo get_the_title( $post->ID ) ?></h3>
          <p><?php echo get_the_excerpt( $post->ID ) ?></p>
          <p class="posts-item-date"><?php echo get_the_date() ?></p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <?php } ?>
  
  <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
  
</div>
```

Comment: К сожалению не сработало :(

Comment: @foreigndezigner а что получилось?

Comment: все тоже самое, выводит последние изображения из папки uploads. Причем на странице статей (где выводится не 4 поста, а все), с методом if ( have_posts() ) изображение работает без postdata.

Comment: @foreigndezigner этот фрагмент вставляется в шаблоне внутри глобального цикла?

Comment: Код, который выводит 4 записи? Да, через админку, как сниппет.

Comment: @foreigndezigner вызов first_post_image() хоть раз происходит?

Comment: Не понимаю, как это проверить, но думаю, что происходит, раз он вызывает последнее изображение из загруженных (но не относящихся к посту).

Comment: Остальные вызовы, типа the_permalink не срабатывают без $post->ID, возможно проблема в этом..

Comment: @foreigndezigner немного скорректировал код. попробуйте сейчас

Comment: Сработало, спасибо ОГРОМНОЕ! Почти 2 дня с этой бедой сижу ковыряюсь)